# Is possible applying virtual memory with cloud disk (cloud storage) instead of local disk (SSD/HDD)?

Tags: virtual-memory

I heard concept of virtual memory is using disk to save temporary progress or data instruction (temporary data). About temporary data, it's main job of physical memory (RAM) so that's mean virtual memory is helping main job of physical memory.

Virtual memory work in software level and hardware level. Even though my major is focus to hardware (Computer System) but i'm still not sure how it works. As far i know, virtual memory is handled by Memory Management Unit in hardware level. While in software level it handled by OS that maybe applying contigous method or non-contigous.

We know that when applying virtual memory the computer using local storage/disk like SSD. SSD is match for virtual memory since R/W speed of SSD is faster than HDD. But how about applying virtual memory with cloud disk instead of local disk? Then it will be interested. We can assume the speed of internet is good enough. I notice i can mount my local PC to google drive, so that's mean can i use them as virtual memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thirty years ago Sun Microsystems was selling diskless workstations that accessed all mass storage (root, user directories, virtual memory / swap) over 10Mbit Ethernet, which is considerably slower than high-speed Internet connections today.  Those machines even bootstrapped themselves over the network.  So it is certainly possible to have swap disks exist and function in the cloud.  Assuming you have a block-level interface to such storage (e.g. a [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network) and local support), it should also be straightforward to set up.  I struggle to imagine a situation where such a setup would be desirable today, however.